Piona.us did they Merge w/Bitcoin
Has their been a merger with piona.us? They want you to use them to make them your Bitcoin wallet and want a fee, plus what they want in their terms.
What happens to the blockchain that I made. When I tried to withdraw, I was transferred to pione.us. Help


Piona.us did they Merge w/Bitcoin

No.
Bitcoin is not an organisation, it cannot be merged into a business or organisation.

They want you to use them to make them your Bitcoin wallet and want a fee

Unexpected fees are generally a clear sign of deception and fraud.
